# Mutable Swift array becomes NSArray when I initialize with Obj-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays, swift, swift2

I'm creating my base models in Swift(2.0) and then controlling the views in Objective-C.  I'm still new to Swift, so hopefully I'm just overlooking something simple, but here is the problem:

I’m making a mutable array in Swift, but when I initialize the array in my Objective-c portion of the program, it becomes an `NSArray`, more specifically it becomes: `Swift._SwiftDeferredNSArray`

Why is it becoming immutable when I initialize?  Here’s my Swift code:

```
import Foundation

@objc public class Model : NSObject {

    var books:[Book]

    override init(){
        self.books = [Book]()
    }

}
```

And here’s my Obj-c Code;

```
Model *bookCollection = [[Model alloc]init];
```

I’m unable to add objects to my `bookCollection.books` array (because it has become an `NSArray`) and when I set a breakpoint and po it, I can see that it is a `Swift._SwiftDeferredNSArray`.  **bookCollection.books is supposed to be an `NSMutableArray`.**

Any thoughts?

Comment: Try putting the `dynamic` keyword in front of the `books` declaration.

Comment: Just tried   dynamic var books:[Book]
, unfortunately it didn't change anything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In swift, the difference between mutable and immutable array is;

```
var books:[Book] // is a mutable array
let books:[Book] = [book1, book2]; // is immutable array due to let
```

but I don't think, same rule is followed when bridging to ObjC.

Just for a fix, you may have mutableArray specifically.

```
import Foundation

@objc public class Model : NSObject {

    var books:NSMutableArray = NSMutableArray();

    override init(){
        super.init();
        // other code
    }

}
```

You will need to parse the values to Book Class when retrieving from the array.

Comment: Thank you!  I'll mark this as the correct answer but is this the correct way to initialize my array in Swift in the ovverride init method:  self.books = []  Or is there a more proper way?

Comment: There is an option to initialize it with it's definition as I did but I do not see any issue if you initialize the same in your init().

Answer (score 3):

> bookCollection.books is supposed to be an NSMutableArray.

No, it is not. `Var` does not mean that the bridged Objective-C object is to be mutable: it means that the property can be assigned to.

The Swift array type is a structure, not a class. This has important bridging implications. The reference itself cannot be shared without passing it as an `inout` value, and even then the references cannot be stored. If it bridged as a `NSMutableArray`, it would be possible to have undetectable mutating references, and Swift does not allow that.

You should be able to assign a new `NSArray` to your property from Objective-C code, though. For instance, this should work:

```
bookCollection.books = [bookCollection.books arrayByAddingObject:myNewBook];
```

Your other option, obviously, is to declare `books` as a `NSMutableArray` from the Swift side.